# Use Touch ID with Elevating Privileges

Tags: macos, cocoa

Does anyone know how to combine elevating privileges with Touch ID?

I am using `AuthorizationCopyRights` to get the rights and run a command lie as an administrator. Everything works properly but I wanna make it easily for users by using Touch ID and not typing the password each time. Unfortunately I didn't find how to combine `LAContext` that's used for authentication and the code that I use now.

Comment: Can you please show your code that you are using now?

Comment: @AgentBilly sure. Now I am using `AuthorizationCopyRights` and `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` then to run with privileges